# xamarin.forms Selected Item color in rounded corner listview

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have rounded corner listview that i rendered in andoid.

When i select item - the background color is drawn as rectangle, regardless of the edges of the list view.

How do i set the background color of the selected item to be till the end of the listview ?

Comment: Hve the items rounded corners or only the ListView? Screenshot?

Comment: The listview has rounded corners, when I select item, by default the background color is in square shape and I want it to be at the boarders of the listview for each item selected